# How to make an image (div) follow the cursor within a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, cursor, jquery-animate

This image is a static div duplicate of the cursor trailimage. One is fixed, the other follows the cursor. How would I code the static div image to follow the cursor?

refer to this image http://deverexdrawer.deviantart.com/art/Trailimage-538913342

**Trailimage javascript excerpts**

```
var trailimage=["images/contact/gardening-glove-cursor.png", , ]
var offsetfrommouse=[-110,5]
var displayduration=0

if (document.getElementById || document.all)
    document.write('<div id="trailimageid" style="position:absolute;visibility:visible;left:0px;top:100px;width:1px;height:1px"><img border="0" src="'+trailimage[0]+'"></div>')

function followmouse(e){
    var xcoord=offsetfrommouse[0]
    var ycoord=offsetfrommouse[1]
    if (typeof e != "undefined"){
        xcoord+=e.pageX
        ycoord+=e.pageY
}

</script>
```

Static div image

```
...<img border="0" src="'+trailimage[0]+'"
onmousedown="this.src=trailimage[1]"   
onmouseup="this.src=trailimage[0]" />...
```

assuming

```
var trailimage=[
  "images/contact/gardening-glove-cursor.png",
  "images/contact/gardening-glove-cursor_down.png" ]
```

Comment: where have you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://jsfiddle.net/n4foofvm/1/

html

```
<div id="movingDiv">
    <img id="barber" class="barber-image" src="1.jpg" />
</div>
```

css

```
#movingDiv{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

javascript

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $("#movingDiv").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
});
```